# Remove CSS from select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I had more than one css applied to an input, one default and others to customize. I want to disable the css default but not the others. I tried to remove with:

```
$j('#teste').css("max-width", "");
```

and

```
$j('#teste').removeAttr("max-width");
```

Those ways, remove all css. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: removeAttr is not for CSS .. it's for the tag's attribute. http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr

Comment: I believe that the problem is in your CSS and not in jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you have a global max-width set and you want to override it for `#teste`? Either way this should do what you require:

```
$j('#teste').css("max-width", "none");
```

As others have mentioned this can be done with straight CSS:

```
#teste {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple extension function I've written for our project that removes inline CSS attribute(s) previously set by $(...).css(). It alters only the 'style' attribute - if a style is set through a class, you need to remove the whole class or override the style.

You use it as $(...).removeCss('color', 'font-weight');

```
$.fn.removeCss = function() {
  var removedCss = $.makeArray(arguments);
  return this.each(function() {
    var e$ = $(this);
    var style = e$.attr('style');
    if (typeof style !== 'string') return;
    style = $.trim(style);
    var styles = style.split(/;+/);
    var sl = styles.length;
    for (var l = removedCss.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      var r = removedCss[i];
      if (!r) continue;
      for (var j = 0; j < sl;) {
        var sp = $.trim(styles[j]);
        if (!sp || (sp.indexOf(r) === 0 && $.trim(sp.substring(r.length)).indexOf(':') === 0)) {
          styles.splice(j, 1);
          sl--;
        } else {
          j++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (styles.length === 0) {
      e$.removeAttr('style');
    } else {
      e$.attr('style', styles.join(';'));
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

use css classes and add/remove them to control the styles.

```
$('#id').addClass('foo');

$('#id').removeClass('foo');
```

Comment: errr how do you mean. It didnt remove the class from the element? Maybe if you could post more code and elaborate your issues.

Answer (score 2):

$.toggleClass() may work best if you have a stylesheet with a unique class for the "custom" styles that need to be applied after the default and then quickly removed.

```
$('selector').toggleClass('foo');
```

This will add the foo class if it's not present, and remove it if the element(s) doesn't have the foo class. See the [jQuery toggleClass documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass)

If all of your styling is inline () you can use the removeAttr method:

```
$('selector').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (as other people have already stated) remove styling that is applied through stylesheets.  You can, however, override styling.  For example, if max-width is applied through a stylesheet you should be able to override it by changing the value or setting it to 'auto':

```
$('#teste').css("max-width", "999999px");
```

or possibly:

```
$('#teste').css("max-width", "auto");
```

That being said, I agree with the other posts that the best bet is probably just to fix your css and possibly toggle styling by toggling a class.